# Spring Data JPA joining two or more entites

Tags: mysql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have three entities,

```
@Entity
public class Deck {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private int number;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "deck")
    private Set<Lab> labs;

    //getter and setter methods

}

@Entity
public class Lab {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Deck deck;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "lab")
    private Set<LabBooking> labBooking;

    //getter and setter methods

}

@Entity
public class LabBooking {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private Date startTime;
    private Date endTime;

    @ManyToOne
    private Lab lab;

    //getter and setter methods

}
```

Following is the LabRepository,

```
public interface LabRepository extends CrudRepository<Lab, Integer>{

    @Query("SELECT l FROM Lab l JOIN l.labBooking lb WHERE l.deck.id = :deckId AND lb.startTime > '2016-02-24 15:00:00'")
    List<Lab> findLabs(@Param("deckId") int deckId);

}
```

I am trying to retrieve the list of Labs in a deck which are occupied from a particular time.

When I execute the equivalent query (`SELECT * FROM lab l JOIN lab_book lb ON l.id = lb.lab_id WHERE l.deck_id = 9999 AND lb.start_time > '2016-02-24 15:00:00'`) in MySQL, I am getting the following result

```
id      name    deck_id id  end_time            start_time          lab_id
9001    Lab One 9999    5   2016-02-24 17:00:00 2016-02-24 16:00:00 9001
```

In the spring application I am getting the following result,

```
[{
    "lab_id": 9001,
    "lab_name": "Lab One",
    "lab_booking": [{
        "id": 4,
        "start_time": "2016-02-24 15:00:00",
        "end_time": "2016-02-24 16:00:00"
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "start_time": "2016-02-24 16:00:00",
        "end_time": "2016-02-24 17:00:00"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "start_time": "2016-02-24 14:00:00",
        "end_time": "2016-02-23 14:30:00"
    }]
}]
```

The Lab object was supposed to contain only the booking id 5, instead it shows all the ids.

If the sql query return 5 records, then the repository returns 5 Lab objects which are duplicate. What may be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your missing distinct.

```
SELECT distinct l FROM Lab l JOIN l.labBooking lb WHERE l.deck.id = :deckId AND lb.startTime > '2016-02-24 15:00:00'"
```

Comment: Yes. distinct will remove the duplicates. But the Room object still returns all the LapBooking.

Comment: Ok I undestand what are you trying to accomplish and I am sorry that I have to tell you that it does not work the way you want. In this situation hibernate returns you the Lab object in exact the way it is represented in the database. This is necessary since the state might gets written back to the database. It should be possible to return a map with the Lab and responsible LabBooking objects. But I would just request the LabBook objects instead of the Lab objects. Creating of a map afterwards is just a simple lambda expression. If you need help with that just ask.